# Cannot save file in WebStorm 9

Tags: webstorm

I have been using the same workflow for months to add a new page in my ASP .NET site, but all of a sudden I am getting problems with trying to save a `.ascx` file inside of WebStorm.

I created the `.ascx` page in VS and then saved it. I then go over to WebStorm to start developing and I cannot save any of these new files.  I get this error:

```
Following errors occurred on attepmt to save files:

C:\...\Management\Management.ascx___jb_bak___ (Access is denied)
```

I don't get what this file is and why it can't be saved... The `jb` makes it seem like a JetBrains file, but this file doesn't actually exist in the filesystem. All the other files I have had work just fine. Its just this new file all of a sudden.

What does this error even mean.. there is no valuable information

Comment: error means that the file can't be saved because it's been used by another process, so WebStorm is not permitted to change it. Make sure that no other programs are using your file (VS, for example)

Comment: I faced the same issue, did you resolved it?

Comment: Check that you have write permissions on your parent directory (I suddenly and unexpectedly lost that and got this error!)  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32428456/125246

Comment: Next time try disabling ["Use "save write" (save changes to temporary file first)] option in webstorm>>settings>system settings. I thinks this is what's causing the trouble.
I came accros this setting when noticed that filewatcher not always gets file change notifications while this setting is on.
NOTE: use with caution as it is some sort of "safe write"

Answer (score 8):

This error happened to me everytime I used `Nodemon` to start `Webpack` on a separate process. The problem was fixed by disabling "Safe write" in "Settings", as VyvIT suggested.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9r0D.png]

Answer (score 1):

Hello to Developers using Jetbrains products!
I had this problem today and I think it was for the webstorm but I check my E: drive that I was developing on.
The problem was with my hard drive that changed to read-only.

I changed my drive to C and it solved.

Check your drive that you are using. That might be the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your security options for user in **Windows**: 
Right Click

The Folder > Properties > Security Tab

Click on

Edit to change Permissions > Select User